# Impressions rise, Google position declines?

Tags: seo, redirects, https, google-ranking, rel-canonical

I redesigned my one-page website lately and launched it before 2 weeks. I have had some negative volatility on Google and also my website declined which I somehow expected since I did not / couldn't make 301 redirection properly (only rel-canonical and htaccess which I could). I also got my HTTPS domain.

What I am struggling with right now is that, the webpages are indexed but not rising and somehow I get more impressions and clicks than before but Google position on WMT seems to go down then again slightly up then again down.

Of course I am not expecting within 15 days to see some great impact on Google but I thing should at least be seeing my site slightly growing since I have way better website and way better SEO.

So here are the questions:

1. Is that kind of behavior normal and what behavior can I expect for the next month?
2. Is it ok if I use htaccess redirect to HTTPS www site and also rel canonical on each webpage?

Comment: Site size and structure really matters. If your site is small, you will have trouble reaching search users and therefore ranking well.

Comment: @paranoic You seem to have logged in with/created a different user to the user who asked the question?! This is going to prevent you from responding to comments, editing and accepting answers. You need to respond with the same user, or perhaps ask another question and get this deleted by the mods?

Comment: @w3dk, sorry for maybe breking the rules of the forum but i am not exactly sure what you mean by changing a user. thx.

Comment: @paranoic It's not "breaking the rules" as such, it's just not using the site correctly, which means you lose "functionality". You seem to have connected to the site as two different users (both called "paranoic"). The user "paranoic" that asked the question is a different user that wrote that last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ranking changes (dancing up and down) are normal after a website change is made. Google does this on purpose so that it makes it more difficult to back engineer it's algorithm(s). It may take a few weeks before things settle.

.htaccess can be used to 301 redirect your old urls. This would be the best way to direct search engine crawlers. If you cannot 301, then canonical would be the next best option.

Lastly, it's possible to get more overall impressions even though ranking is lower for the keywords you are looking at because more (other) keywords are now being ranked due your changes.

Comment: thx yan for respond, i somehow just dont get to change the users so i can comment directly. anyway, i have htaccess redirect command and rel-canonical at the same time. is it ok and can it be harmful?
also after 2 weeks some of my pages werent yet indexed on WMT, why is that? i opened 4 diferent accounts for diferent URLs. at some are one pages indexend and at some others. should i keep on tracking each URL (ex. http://example.com, https://www.example.com etc.)?

Comment: If you have a 301 redirect in htaccess for a page, then nothing will be reading the old page as it being directed right away to the new page. So a rel-canon on the old link won't matter much, and certainly wont hurt.
Webmasters tools doesn't show all of the links that are indexed. (Not sure if that answers your second part)